# Stop JavaFX TreeView from "Jumping" When an item is expanded

Tags: javafx

I created a simple javafx treeview. When I expand an Item in the TreeView, the item I expanded "jumps" upward to make room for the expanded items, sometimes even pushing the expanded item past the top of the viewable space.

I don't want it to do that. I want the item I clicked on to stay in the exact same place.

Here is an image illustrating the problem:

[image]

It seems this happens because the scrollpane stays as the same percent of total-height, and the size of the list has changed, so the same percent now is in a different place relative to the highlighted item.

Is there a way to tell the tree view to not do any scrolling in addition to the expand action?

Comment: this happens because it's standard behavior (in win at least, see explorer): the idea is to show as many of the newly expanded children as possible while keeping the parent visible. To change you'll most probably (never tried) a custom TreeSkin

Comment: I do not get the same behavior in windows 7's explorer, looking at the same set of folders. The windows method seems to be: when expanding a folder, do not move the expanded item. However, if the sub-list would push off the bottom of the screen, move the expanded item up to make room for them, but never push it past the top of the window.  That would be great behavior, but this is not doing that.  In javafx's treeview, the item always moves up, and it can even be pushed past the top of the window.

Comment: hmm .. your screenshot seems to show the state that you describe in your comment as "great" _if the sub-list would push off the bottom of the screen, move the expanded item up to make room for them_ Anyway, if the expanded parent item can be pushed off the top or move if there's enough space for the complete sublist (in fx), I would consider it a bug that you might report.

Comment: okay, looks like the skin does nothing special to keep the scroll location on collapse/expand .. simply triggers a rebuildCells on the flow which decides where they are shown. Looks like a lot of work to improve ..

Comment: Yea, I'll improve my post later tonight with a better screenshot and narrative. The example I highlighted with the picture is not actually a problem, although there are serious problems.

Comment: I'm wondering simply calling "scrollTo(expandedItem)" after an expansion would emulate the windows behavior. I will try it tonight and post my findings.

Comment: hi,you have any method to stop jump?